# How to use VBA to copy data from one sheet to another if it fulfill three different conditions?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to copy data that fulfil a few criteria from one sheet to another using VBA.

**My goal:**
Copy Cell in column E, F and G in Sheet FP to column R, S and T in Sheet MUOR if it meets my conditions.

**My conditions:**

(1) Cell in Column D & Cell in Column P (in Sheet MUOR) must meet the condition in Column I of Sheet FP.

(2) If Cell in Column D is empty, skip to next Cell in Column D.

(3) Column R, S or T must be empty before pasting it. If not empty, move to the next cell that meets the condition. (Do not replace or duplicate the data)

**Other information:**  Max *Batch No (Column D)* per day is 3;

**Issue Facing:**
My current VBA code doesn't recognise my conditions. It totally ignored my Day 1 data, and it duplicated all the Day 2 data.

Please refer to the attached images.

Sheet MUOR
[image]

Sheet FP
[image]

My expected Result
[image]

[**Sample Data here**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K8dEOPTxfXSZ-DynJiwikoaHF53EgP8l/view?usp=sharing)

My current code as below:

```
Sub LinkData()

Dim y As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim arr As Variant
Dim FP As Worksheet
Dim MUOR As Worksheet

Set FP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FP")
Set MUOR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MUOR")

With FP
   lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:I" & lr).Value
End With

With MUOR
    For y = 11 To 363
    For z = y - 1 To y + 8
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

    If Cells(11 + y, 4) <> "" And Cells(11 + y, 4) & Cells(10 + z, 16) = arr(x, 9) And IsEmpty(Cells(10 + z, 18)) Then
            .Cells(10 + z, 18) = arr(x, 5)
            .Cells(10 + z, 19) = arr(x, 8)
            .Cells(10 + z, 20) = arr(x, 7)
            Else
            End If
    Next x
    Next z
    Next y


End With

End Sub
```

Any VBA expert please help me.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Please note that you haven't actually asked a question. If your code doesn't work please describe any errors and where they occur.

Comment: You're missing some dots at line `if .Cells(11+y,` hence these `Cells(` refer to `Activesheet` instead of MUOR.

Comment: Check how your code works... On the first loop (y=11, z=10) you are trying to match Cells(22,4) & Cells(20,16) against arr(2,9). Cell 22,4 is blank...

Comment: ¿Can you post/upload a data sample somwhere? Replying your data takes too long and

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego thanks for pointing out. I have amended that part. However, the data is still duplicating. Can I set a condition that is if `Cells(z, 18)` has value in it, VBA just skip that z and loop to the next z?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I have uploaded a link in my question above. Or you can click this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K8dEOPTxfXSZ-DynJiwikoaHF53EgP8l/view?usp=sharing) Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think code below should give expected output, but not totally sure, since the workbook uploaded/shared seems to differ from the screenshots in the question.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub LinkData()

    Dim arrayFromFPSheet() As Variant
    arrayFromFPSheet = GetSourceArray()

    Dim MUOR As Worksheet
    Set MUOR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MUOR")

    Dim rangesToLoopThrough As Range
    Set rangesToLoopThrough = GetDestinationAreas(MUOR)

    With MUOR
        Dim area As Range
        For Each area In rangesToLoopThrough.Areas
            Debug.Assert area.Rows.CountLarge > 1 And area.Rows.CountLarge < 20

            Dim areaFirstRowIndex As Long
            areaFirstRowIndex = area.Rows(1).Row

            Dim areaLastRowIndex As Long
            areaLastRowIndex = area.Rows(area.Rows.Count).Row

            Dim readRowIndex As Long
            For readRowIndex = areaFirstRowIndex To areaLastRowIndex
                If Not IsCellEmpty(.Cells(readRowIndex, "D")) Then

                    Dim batchNumber As String
                    batchNumber = CStr(.Cells(readRowIndex, "D"))

                    Dim writeRowIndex As Long
                    For writeRowIndex = areaFirstRowIndex To areaLastRowIndex
                        If IsCellEmpty(.Cells(writeRowIndex, "R")) And IsCellEmpty(.Cells(writeRowIndex, "S")) And IsCellEmpty(.Cells(writeRowIndex, "T")) Then

                            Dim Grade As String
                            Grade = CStr(.Cells(writeRowIndex, "P"))

                            Dim batchNumberAndGrade As String
                            batchNumberAndGrade = batchNumber & Grade

                            Dim n As Variant
                            n = Application.CountIfs(.Range("P" & areaFirstRowIndex, "P" & writeRowIndex), Grade, .Range("R" & areaFirstRowIndex, "R" & writeRowIndex), batchNumber) + 1
                            Debug.Assert IsNumeric(n)

                            Dim sourceRowIndex As Long
                            sourceRowIndex = GetRowIndexOfNthMatch(n, arrayFromFPSheet, batchNumberAndGrade, 9)

                            If sourceRowIndex > 0 Then
                                .Cells(writeRowIndex, "R") = arrayFromFPSheet(sourceRowIndex, 5)
                                .Cells(writeRowIndex, "S") = arrayFromFPSheet(sourceRowIndex, 8)
                                .Cells(writeRowIndex, "T") = arrayFromFPSheet(sourceRowIndex, 7)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next writeRowIndex
                End If
            Next readRowIndex
        Next area
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetDestinationAreas(ByVal someSheet As Worksheet) As Range
    ' Crudely clusters/groups destination sheet into areas (which
    ' should be date-specific, although this function will not check/verify
    ' output).
    Const START_ROW_INDEX As Long = 10

    Dim outputRange As Range
    Set outputRange = someSheet.Range("C" & START_ROW_INDEX, "C" & someSheet.Rows.Count)

    On Error Resume Next
    Set outputRange = outputRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' Will raise error if no constants found.
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Assert Not (outputRange Is Nothing)

    Set GetDestinationAreas = outputRange
End Function

Private Function GetSourceArray() As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FP")
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Dim outputArray() As Variant
        outputArray = .Range("A1:I" & lastRow).Value
    End With
    GetSourceArray = outputArray
End Function

Private Function IsCellEmpty(ByVal someCell As Range) As Boolean
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function
    ' "IsEmpty only returns meaningful information for variants."
    ' So using below function instead.
    IsCellEmpty = Len(CStr(someCell.Value)) = 0
End Function

Private Function GetRowIndexOfNthMatch(ByVal n As Long, ByRef someArray() As Variant, ByVal someText As String, ByVal targetColumn As Long) As Long
    ' Returns a 1-based row index of the nth occurrence of text value
    ' in target column of array or 0 if unsuccessful.
    Debug.Assert n > 0

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = LBound(someArray, 1) To UBound(someArray, 1)
        If someArray(rowIndex, targetColumn) = someText Then
            Dim matchCount As Long
            matchCount = matchCount + 1

            If matchCount = n Then
                GetRowIndexOfNthMatch = rowIndex
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next rowIndex
End Function
```

Thanks for all the information you provided in the question. It makes it easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks mate! I run my file with your code, it is working but I noticed when there is more than one Batch No in a day, it did not read the second Batch No correctly.I have uploaded the screenshot [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CQsC0DoPYcgksuj6VAaDJMZwfbHzVSxz). The code did not capture the data highlighted. 

Anyway, it was one big step forward to achieve my expected result, thanks again!

Comment: @GanCy, My logic for determining `n` was wrong. Have edited code, if you want to try again.

Comment: it's working now, thanks mate! (Probably need some time for me to understand the code though...)